# How can I grunt clean a node module that is still in use by the gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I'm using grunt-contrib-clean to try to delete the _node_modules_ folder on the build machine at the end of a build.

But I recently added a new node module dependency, *grunt-sass*, which is causing the 'clean' task to fail, unable to delete the file `node-sass\bin\win32-x64-v8-3.14\binding.node`.

I *think* the node sass file is still in use, because if I comment out the `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');` shown below, then the clean works.

**Q1: Can I "unload" an npm task, sort of like reversing the `loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass')'?**

**Q2: Is cleaning up by deleting 'node_modules' at the end of the CI build the right thing™ to be doing?**

---

**Details:**

- Windows 7 x64

npm list

```
├─┬ grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0
│ └── rimraf@2.2.8
```

gruntfile.js

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
⋮
clean: {
  post: [
    'node_modules/grunt-sass' // was 'node_modules', but this is for debugging
  ]
}
```

results in error:

```
Running "clean:post" (clean) task
ERROR
Warning: Unable to delete "node_modules" file (EPERM, operation not permitted 'c:\myfold
er\node_modules\grunt-sass\node_modules\node-sass\bin\win32-x64-v8-3.14\binding.node').
Use --force to continue.
```

Note:
There's a *grunt-clean-contrib* [github issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/issues/48) discussing this same exact issue (same file). It has some comments saying that upgrading *rimraf* from v2.2.7 to  v2.2.8 fixed it for them. But I'm using 2.2.8 and still seeing the failure.